# Instalación de Java en Ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu

soy nuevo usuario de ubuntu y una de las primeras operaciones que hice fue desactivar todas las actualizaciones del software.

Ahora intento instalar el java por la terminal y me tira errores de que no encuentra el paquete jdk-jdr. ¿Cual es el problema?, ¿será que desactivé las actualizaciones?, de antemano gracias.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! y lo instalaste ese paquete que pide?

Answer (score 1):

Lo recomendable es actualizar primero los paquetes con el comando `sudo apt-get update` (para abrir nuestra terminal y poder ingresar distintos comandos debemos presionar la secuencia de teclas `ctrl + alt + T`).

Una vez realizado el primer paso procedemos a instalar nuestra jdk con : `sudo apt-get install default-jdk` para una version por defecto.

Finalemente comprobamos que tengamos instalada nuestra jdk con el comando `java -version`

> No te olvides de **sudo** antes de cada comando porque sino vas a tener problemas de falta de permisos al momento de querer instalar.

Quiero tambíen mencionar Iván que Ubuntu tiene un manejo mucho mas performante y "cómodo para el usuario" que windows en cuanto a actualizaciones, por ende te recomiendo que actualizes sin problemas, no se te va a hacer engorroso.

Bienvenido al mundo de linux! no hay vuelta atrás.